# How to serialize and save a stack of objects?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to save a stack of objects, so that the stack will still be there when I close and then reopen the app.

I tried extending Application to create a global variable, but that is deleted when the app closes. I think I should be using Java's internal memory, but don't know how to do so with a stack and not a single object. I am having trouble researching this, as whenever I look for anything with "stack" in the search, everything is about the runtime stack, not the data structure.

Comment: Why does it needs to be a stack ? You could just convert it to an array and store it in Android internal storage, right ?

Comment: A word of advice, do not serialize objects to files if you are making an android application. In the beginning it seems like an easy solution, but when your project grows you will suffer a lot of performance issues and errors that will be hard to solve. You should either save your data in shared preferences if they are simple, or use SQLiteOpenHelper or Room to create a database. That's why they created databases for, to store data correctly and easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to store large data objects is internal SQLite database with help of Room, OrmLiite or other wrapper.

Or if it small values like saved options, time or similar then use SharedPreferences storage

Answer (score 0):

1. The object needs to be serialisable. For this you need to extend your object with Serializable
   https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable
2. You need to store the object to the disk in the form of a file or in a database as a blob.
3. When you start your application you need to deserialize the object and load it into memory.

There is an alternative to the above 3 points though.

There is an open source library called SnappyDb which can persist key value pairs and do serialization and drserialization pretty fast.

https://github.com/nhachicha/SnappyDB

Answer (score -1):

you need to use  sharedPreferences.

i will show you how to save an string and use it .

step1 : `SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;`

step2 : `sharedPreferences= this.getSharedPreferences("ur choosen name",0);`

step3 : `sharedPreferences.getString("mystring","");`

step4 :`sharedPreferences.edit.PutString("mystring","what i want

save").commit();`

now its saved

step5 : `String mystring;`

step6 : `mystring = sharedPreferences.getString("mystring","");`

use step 5 and 6 for using your saved variable

Comment: why not write `SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ur choosen name",0);` and `String mystring = sharedPreferences.getString("mystring","");`. Also, why do you use `.commit()`?

Comment: i just copied from my project ,so do not need to use "this" , and without commit() nothing will happen :)

Comment: yes but it's 2019, please use .apply() instead of .commit. Commit is old fashioned